# Cut command basics

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file named `Test_Cut_command_20170519.csv`. Using `cut` command I need till `Test_Cut_command` i.e. delimiter is `_`. I used the below command but it is not working for me `echo Test_Cut_command_20170519.csv | cut -d "_" -f3`.

Can any one please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo Test_Cut_command_20170519.csv | cut -d "_" -f1-3
```

Output:
         Test_Cut_command

Answer (score 1):

you can specify which elements you want to print:

```
echo "Test_Cut_command_20170519.csv" | cut -d "_" -f 1,2,3
```

OR you can pass a range:

```
echo "Test_Cut_command_20170519.csv" | cut -d "_" -f 1-3
```

Output:

```
Test_Cut_command
```

`-f` is for telling cut command which field you would like to print after the delimiter, in your case you need to print the first 3 fields.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @teepu you are welcome, and please don't forget to mark your question as answer.

Comment: @MostafaHussein definitely you have first answered the question

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Test_Cut_command_20170519.csv" | cut -d "_" -f 1-3
```

Output: Test_Cut_command